# free alternative to DVDFab for OS X?

Tags: backup

so I'm wondering if there's a free alternative to DVDFab. I mainly want to make ***unencrypted backups (to ISO file)*** of my DVDs. and in some instances, I want to shrink the DVDs from DVD9 to DVD5 size.

Thanks :)

ps. I've looked around the net and no --recent-- discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Handbrake is a great free utility for ripping DVDs. It does require the free libdvdcss but the first time you try and rip an encrypted DVD Handbrake will prompt you to download and install it. It's pretty easy.

That will get you a movie file of your choice but not an .iso. There are apps that will do that. iMovie, iDVD, Toast, etc. will all take a movie file and burn it to a DVD or .iso